How can I alter the result of libpysal.weights.W to remove connections based on shared edge length?
I'm using libpysal.weights.W (mostly Rook) to compute a connectivity matrix.
Sadly my input data polygons are not perfect and I'd like to remove connections based on the shared edges of the polygons. I know how to do it with w.sparse, but not on the original object.
Right now I do the following:
G = w.to_networkx()

edges = nx.to_pandas_edgelist(G)

[... code to alter the edges with networkx ...]

w = nx.to_scipy_sparse_array(G)

How can I remove connection in a libpysal.weights.W object programatically or convert a sparse matrix to a libpysal.weights.W object?

I've figured it out at least if you go along the networkx route I've described in my question.
To convert a sparse matrix to a libpysal.weights.W object you need to do the following:
from libpysal.weights import WSP


G = w.to_networkx()

edges = nx.to_pandas_edgelist(G)

[... code to alter the edges with networkx ...]

sparse_matrix = nx.to_scipy_sparse_array(G)

w = WSP(sparse_matrix).to_W()

